# How to make Microsoft OneDrive use JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, office-js, onedrive

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask. If so, please let me know!

So I'm generating HTML files, and I am uploading them to *OneDrive* for other faculty and staff. These reports rely on JavaScript to neatly highlight the rows, and when I view the files directly in OneDrive the JavaScript does not display. Viewing the files in the browser works fine.

Is there a way to enable JavaScript when viewing these in OneDrive? Should I upload them to SharePoint instead to enable JavaScript, or would it be easier to do something else?

If it matters, the JavaScript is inside a *script* tag within the head of the document, and is called as follows:

```
<head>
     <script>  
          function warnings(){
             /* function logic */
          }
     </script>
</head>

<body onload="warnings()">
<!--tables and the like-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do they have to remain HTML Files? You could convert them to PDF using the HTML2PDF library, and simply upload the PDF file which would include the highlights that were on the HTML file. Unless it as to be an HTML file uploaded for some reason or another.

Comment: They don't have to by any means, but they just are easier to generate as HTML files. I'll look into that library.

Comment: There's a link to the library, you can install it using npm. It's relatively simple to use, you can select dom elements to print into PDF meaning if you wanted a whole page printed you'd select the HTML element and incorporate page breaks semantically of course into your html.